# Redirect and modify query string

Tags: jquery, regex, apache, redirect, query-string

I've been struggling with some htaccess redirects. I just spent some time reading and searching on stack and couldn't get an answer that works with my scenario.

I want to redirect `abc.com/knowledge-base/QUERY` to
`xyz.com/display/GKB/New_QUERY`.

Here is what i did:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} knowledge-base/(.*).html$ 
RewriteRule xyz.com/display/GKB/?/new_query
```

It didn't work. Any tip what I do wrong?

Comment: Add a language tag (jquery?) to your question and more people will find it.

Comment: Then post it please.

Comment: looks like i found the answer. redirect knowledge-base/QUERY to xyz.com//display/GKB/new_QUERY